# Не работает команда, просто не реагирует

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

сделал команду что бы выводила температуру и т.д
Ну что то не работает, не могу понять почему, ошибок нету.
Вот сам код.

```
import discord
import asyncio 
import datetime
# import requests
# import json
import pyowm
import random

from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils import config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps
from discord.ext import commands


owm = OWM('e25bc8f**88888888')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()

# api_key = 'e25bc8f098a***************'
# command_prefix = '!w'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', self_bot = False)
client.remove_command('help')



@client.command()
async def w(ctx, *, region):
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(region)
    w = observation.get_weather()
    print(w)
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]
    cloud = w.detailed_status 
    rain = w.rain
    window = w.wind()["speed"]
    emb = discord.Embed(title = f'**Погода в {region}**', colour = discord.Color.purple())
    emb.add_field(name = f'Погода: {cloud}\nТемпература: {temp}\nДождь: {rain}\nВетер: {window}',value = f'Вот такая погода в {region} на сегодняшний день')
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Comment: Наверное следует запустить бота в блоке `if __name__  == "__main__"`

Comment: к сожалению не помогло

Comment: @LooneyRojers, а вы пробовали без бота вызывать эту функцию? Например, с выводом в консоль? Все работает?